# ParseError Invalid Character with cElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to iteratively parse a tree with a checksum at the end, using:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
for event, elem in et.iterparse("C:\myXMLfile.xml"):
    if elem.tag == "Signature":
        elem.clear()
```

This raises a `ParseError: reference to invalid character number: line 4205, column 25` at this character: `<Signature value="e?'O;????5?u??c???]????<??jX" />`

I thought the `elem.clear()` statement would be a way around that, but it seems like it processes the attribute before clearing.  Is there a way I can clear this element without processing it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I wound up doing:

1. Read XML file as text into memory.
2. Use a regular expression to find the  tag.
3. Delete everything between the opening and closing tag.
4. Rewrite to XML file.
5. Parse new XML file.
6. Go on my merry way.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [definition of xml.etree.cElementTree.iterparse](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse), you will notice that there is the optional parameter of events where you can report back on the "start" event ("end" event by default). You can leverage that to perform elem.clear() after the start event and continue on to end event as double-branch `if` statement.

Comment: I've changed the code so that it is now: `for event, elem in et.iterparse("C:\myXMLfile.xml"): if event == "start" and elem.tag == "Signature": elem.clear()`

Unfortunately, that produces the same result.

Comment: The only alternative I can think of, off the top of my head is to iterate through and remove the `Signature` tags and then perform an iterparse. This would cause negligible impact to performance as it is still in the same order.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm not sure how to implement that in this case; apparently the 'start' event looks for the closing ">" of the opening tag.

As to removing the `Signature` tag, I think that's what I'm going to have to do, although I'm not sure how best to do that either, other than a line-by-line file write.

Comment: How about using process like this: `tree = xml.parse("C:\myXMLfile.xml")`. Then grab the root `rootNode = tree.getroot()` and using findall("Signature") to get the elements with the Signature tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, the parser throws the error when loading the Signature tag into memory.  I think I may try to use a RE to delete the Signature line and then load everything into memory.